# How to get the code and state from the callback URL of oauth in linkedin authetication

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to access the linkedIn api from my servlet, i am using OAuth Service.I am able to login from my application to the linkedIn account.Like i am posting the screen shot.[image]

This is working fine .But the problem is that i am not able to get the value from the call back url.i.e

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    /*String callbackUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    HttpSession mySession = request.getSession();
    */
    String authUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=787mznyz5nn2nl&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2FConnectSocialMedia%2F&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424";

    //System.out.println("1st URL: "+authUrl);


    response.sendRedirect(authUrl);
    String query = request.getQueryString();
    System.out.println("Query is -->"+query);
```

Can anyone help me to get the code and state after the allow access button??

Answer (score 1):

The `OAuth` dance works like the following:

1. User attempts authentication to your site/app
2. Your app/site redirects the user to the oauth service provider(LinkedIn), therby passing on as a parameter a `redirect url`
3. User authenticates with oauth service provider and grants privileges to your site/app
4. The auth service provider redirects the user back to the url you provided in step 2
5. Your site/app must handle the redirected request and extract the oauth token

You need to implement 2 handlers - one for redirecting to LinkedIn with an redirect url provided and a second for accepting the redirect and extracting the token. From your description and code my surmise is that you have implemented half of the first handler.

Comment: But i am not able to get the response from the call back .can you help in that??

Comment: @lucifer can you post the (relative) url that the authenticated user is redirected to? How are you handling this redirect request?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=75--a5377fb9-08fb-4ba9-bb34-a64fbaf199f5

Comment: @lucifer This is the url you redirect the user to in step 2. It seems you are using the old oauth 1.x API. Check the [OAuth2 API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2). It states that you need to provide a `redirect_uri` as a parameter. In addition to that you need to implement the handler (e.g. @Controller in Spring) to obtain the access token from this uri. (see steps 4 and 5 from answer and section 2 from the API Docs).

Comment: that means i have to extract the access token from this using that api.But actually i am not getting any code reference that  i can use in mine .

Comment: I am able to send the redirect uri to the linkedIn and also can do allow access ,but now i am trying to get the call back uri's code and state how i can do that?

Comment: String authUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=787mznyz5nn2nl&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2FConnectSocialMedia%2F&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424";
        
        //System.out.println("1st URL: "+authUrl);
  
        response.sendRedirect(authUrl); this is my call back url how to extract the code and state?

Comment: can you  help once i have generated the redirect url and can do the allow access but how to get that code and state???